# Link blocks to composer in Concrete5

Tags: concrete5

I'm just playing about with an offline copy of Concrete5 and was wondering if there is any way to link blocks to the composer system to make them work? I made a page template hoping I could just click 'new page' and select my template to add it to the right area of my test site, but it won't show up. I then tried to edit a preset page template from my theme, and that worked fine... except it still populates the new page with the original blocks.

It seems like a total nightmare to do anything in this system. Should I be using  a different one if I can't even do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question but have you had a look at this tutorial? It might help https://documentation.concrete5.org/tutorials/setup-a-simple-blog-within-concrete-5-7

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I think I'm going to quit Concrete. It's so slow and complicated it's hard to even ask for help, never mind understand the answers. :P